# Do I need a separate NAT gateway for each private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

On AWS, let's say I have 3 private subnets in 3 different AZs and I want all of them to be able to access the internet through a NAT gateway. [AWS guides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html) suggest having separate NAT gateways and bastion hosts for each subnet (assuming they're needed of course). Needless to mention, everything is in the same VPC (and consequently the same region).

Is there going to be a performance penalty for sharing the same NAT gateway for all private subnets?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The performance penalty for traffic going between AZs is minor (single-digit millisecond latency).

The real reason for using multiple NAT Gateways is for high-availability.

If there is a single NAT Gateway and that AZ should fail, then all private instances would lose Internet access. Having a NAT Gateway in each AZ ensures high availability.

If you are not too concerned about a potentially rare occurrence, you can save money by using only one NAT Gateway.

(A NAT Gateway is redundant within a single AZ.)

Comment: Looking at VPC pricing, one NAT gateway per AZ could also be more cost effective (depending on the use case): "There will be data transfer charge between your NAT Gateway and EC2 instance if they are in the different availability zone"

Comment: but what will happen if i provide 2 NAT gateway in private subnet route table

Comment: @dev You can have a NAT Gateway in two different public subnets (each in a different AZ). Then, create different Route Tables for the private subnets (that are also in different AZs). The route table for AZ-1 will point to the NAT in AZ-1. The route table for AZ-2 will point to the NAT in AZ-2. So, instead of "providing 2 NAT Gateways in private subnet route table", you would have two separate Route Tables.

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein this approach will be correct , i think its highly unlikely NAT gateway could fail , and actually i don't think we can specify 2 NAT gateway in same route table , i can not modify and check in my project , and also 2 route table  could be a design consideration